# Show that the polynomial has no roots of multiplicity more than 1

Tags: polynomials

> Show that the polynomial
> $$h(x)= [(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+2k+1)]+[x(x+2) \cdots (x+2k+1)]+[x(x+1)(x+3) \cdots (x+2k+1)]+ \cdots +[x(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+2k)]$$
> has no roots of multiplicity more than $1$.

---

Putting $-i$ into the polynomial, we get $$h(-i)= (-1)^i \cdot (i!) \cdot (2k+1-i)!$$ I tried defining a polynomial $$j(x)=h(-x)-(-1)^x \cdot (x!) \cdot (2k+1-x)!$$ so we get that $0,1,...,2k+1$ are roots of $j(x)$. How do I proceed?

Comment: Your polynomial appears to be a derivative of the polynomial $\omega(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{2k+1}(x+i).$ If it had a root $\alpha$ of multiplicity greater than $1,$ maybe it could happen that it is also a root of $\omega$ (but, I'm not sure).

Comment: When your $w(x)$ has multiple roots , that root will occur in $h(x)=dw/dx$ too , @Invisible , though that says nothing about whether $h(x)$ has multiple roots. We have to actually check whether $h(x)$ & $dh/dx$ have common roots , which will be the multiple root of $h(x)$. Alternatively , we have to show that $P(x)h(x)+dh/dx=1$ for some $P(x)$ , which will show that there is no common root !

Comment: @Prem, that's why I wrote _maybe it could happen_ . I think [Rolle's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, $j$ as you define it, is not a polynomial. As noticed by @Invisible in your comments, $h$ is the derivative of $w(x) = \prod_{i = 0}^{2k + 1} (x + i)$. This polynomial has degree $2k + 2$ and it has $2k + 2$ distinct roots in $\mathbb{R}$ ($0,-1,\ldots,-2k - 1$). Therefore, by Rolle theorem, its derivative $h$ has $2k + 1$ disctinct roots in $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover those roots $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{2k}$ verify for all $i$, $-i < \alpha_i < -i - 1$.

Since all the $\alpha_i$ are pairwise disjoint and their number equals the degree of $h$, they are its only roots and it has no double roots.